# JQuery prop('required', false, (!$(this).is(':checked')) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

(I've already read some other questions about this but none used this method)

I have some hidden fields that their respective checkboxes shows when checked and I'd also like to make these fields required when I check the checkbox and the opposite when unchecking.

When checking:

- Show the input and make it required.

When unchecking:

- Clean the input value, remove the required attribute and hide it again.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working (the required part):

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(event) {
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input').toggleClass('hide', (!$(this).is(':checked')));
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input :checkbox').prop('checked', false, (!$(this).is(':checked')));
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input input').not(':checkbox, .opt').prop('required', true, ($(this).is(':checked')));
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input input').not(':checkbox').val('').not('.opt').prop('required', false, (!$(this).is(':checked')));
  if (this.id == 'price2') {
    $('.sub-rent .input').toggleClass('hide');
    $('.rent :checkbox').prop('checked', false, (!$(this).is(':checked')));
    $('.rent').toggleClass('hide', (!$(this).is(':checked')));
  }
});
```

The html structure divides in three groups:

- A checkbox with a single hidden input
- A checkbox with two hidden inputs
- A checkbox with two checkboxes with two hidden inputs each (the first also with a checkbox).

I'm also looking for the oportunity to know how could I optimze the code as much as possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/j30v4z9k/

Comment: I'm unaware of any implementation of `.prop()` that takes three parameters.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-function in this case it's like a condition.

Comment: Yes, that still takes two parameters: the property name and a function that returns the value.

Comment: @PaulAbbott Ok, if I remove `false` is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PaulAbbott said, `prop()` doesn't take three parameters, so:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(event) {
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input').toggleClass('hide', (!$(this).is(':checked')));
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input :checkbox').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).parent('.item').find('.input input').not(':checkbox').val('').not(':checkbox, .opt').prop('required', ($(this).is(':checked')));
  if (this.id == 'price2') {
    $('.sub-rent .input').toggleClass('hide');
    $('.rent').toggleClass('hide', (!$(this).is(':checked')));
  }
});
```